# Deleting data from a list

Tags: c#

I posted a question 9 days ago but I feel I have more information to add and it would get seen better as a new question. Also I am not allowed to use LINQ so I couldn't use the solution posted

I have a student management tool which allows me to do things such as add, edit and delete students. I have a listbox on the main form which holds studentInfo. I have added the data to the listbox by reading in a CSV containing a column for `studentID` and a column for `studentMark`.

I have a class called `ModuleData` which holds 3 public list structures:

- one to hold all the `StudentID`
- one to hold all the `StudentMarks`
- one to hold all the `studentInfo`(so just the studentID and studentMark but both together.)

My ModuleData class:

```
namespace Assignment_2_module_marks
{
    static class ModuleData
    {
        public static List<string> studentNumber = new List<string>();

        public static List<string> studentMarks = new List<string>();

        public static List<string> studentInfo = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

My form_load to populate the listbox on the mainform with some studentinfo:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string studentRec;  // Declaring string variable

            StreamReader inputFile = File.OpenText("COM122.csv"); 

            while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)  /
            {
                studentRec = inputFile.ReadLine(); 
                ModuleData.studentInfo = studentRec.Split(',').ToList(); 
                ModuleData.studentNumber.Add(ModuleData.studentInfo[0]);  studentNumber
                ModuleData.studentMarks.Add(ModuleData.studentInfo[1]);  
                lstMarks.Items.Add(ModuleData.studentNumber[0] + " : " + ModuleData.studentInfo[1]);
            }
            inputFile.Close(); // closes the file
        }
```

I want to be able to click the 'delete' button on the mainform which then opens a new form called `deleteRecord`. On the delete record form I ask the user for a StudentID and StudentMark. I then want to take those two pieces of data and look through the `StudentInfo` list and check if any students have the ID and Mark that the user entered in the delete form. If there is a student with the ID and Mark that was entered then I want to delete them from the StudentInfo list and then update the listbox on the mainform so that the student isn't there anymore, if no student is found I want an error to display to tell the user the student doesnt exist

I am not sure how to go about this since I am new to C#

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Edit the last paragraph of your question because it's not very clear.

Comment: The structure of your `ModuleData` doesn't feel right to start with.

Comment: @Aybe I edited it, I hope it makes more sense.

Comment: @RamyMohamed Would you be able to clarify? I am new, thanks

Comment: I agree with @RamyMohamed, but you could do using a for loop to find the studentID and then using removeat to delete from the list. Then bind the list again.

Comment: @Kevin How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some psuedo code, I won't write the whole thing for you since this is homework.

```
var deletedID = -1;

for(int i=0; i< ModuleData.studentInfo.Count; i++)
{
    if (ModuleData.studentInfo[i] == studentIDToDelete + " : " + studentMarkToDelete)
    { 
       deletedID = i;
       break;
    }
}

if (deletedID != -1)
//now remove from lists and reload listbox (hint remove at i)
```

A much better way to do this would be to have a students class and fill that object with the students and marks. Then you could bind the list of objects directly to the listbox, and use the same list to delete a student.

Comment: What is studentToDelete?

Comment: What form should I write this code in ? Main form or deleteRecord form

Answer (score 0):

Knowing this is homework I will try and be more informative rather than providing the answer:

First thing you should do is think of the `ModuleData` class as a model:

```
public partial class ModuleData
{
    public  List<string> studentNumber {get; set;}

    public  List<string> studentMarks {get; set;}

    public  List<string> studentInfo {get; set;}
}
```

You can then populate this model by instantiating it and assigning data to it:

```
ModuleData entity = new ModuleDate();
entity.studentNumbder = list1;
entity.studentMarks = list2;
entity.studentInfo = list3;
```

This model will be the object you use to query any datasource and do any `CRUD` to it.

On `Form_Load` iterate through the file and get your variables from the comma delimited string. Use this data to populate your ModuleData object and add it to your listbox.

Once you have your ListBox data source populated you can then use user defined parameters to query your ListBox data source and delete it if need be.

heres some psudo code:

```
foreach(var listItem in lstMarks.Items){
 if listItem is parameters then remove from lstMarks
}
```

I hope this steers you in the right direction.

Comment: Would you be able to explain why you have {get; set;} beside the lists? Just so I can understand. thanks

Comment: @Darren_D19 I updated my answer to better explain the ModuleData model. Get set allows you to  access and mutate the object without creating getter and setter methods separately

Comment: I don't know if I am understanding this incorrectly but you have 3 different different lists? does that mean 3 list boxes? or 3 list structures? also my form_load populates my 3 list structures correctly, is there not a way to use what I already have instead of doing the ```entity.StudentNumber = list1```

Comment: The `{get; set;}` turns the fields into a C# feature called a Property. This has a number of advantages/caveats. The relevant advantage here, is that many lists/tables/etc are designed to automatically find and interact with Properties (making it easy to create and maintain the UI).